# Express recognizes user, but the username is only shown on a single page. Possible Cookie issue

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cookies, pug

I'm building an express app with MongoDB. i have a pug template the nav bar that I am using and am simply trying to display the users name at the top when they are logged in. It works, but only on the page that the user is automatically redirected to after he/she logs in. After that, the name is not visible. I know that my program identifies that a user is logged in, if it didnt, then the login/signup buttons would be present. Instead, I am just given a button that is blank.

nav bar:

```
if user
        a.cta(href='/logout')
          //- img(src="./img/b.jpg", alt="")
          button.header__btn--signup #{fname}
      else
        a.cta(href='/login')
          button.header__btn--login Login
        a.cta(href='/signup')
          button.header__btn--signup Signup
```

here's my session:

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'dirtylittlesecret',
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true,
SameSite: true
```

}))

and a checkID function that I created:

```
    // CHECK ID
exports.checkID = catchAsync(async (req, res, next, val) => {
  const allUsers = await User.find({});

  for (let user of allUsers) {
    if (req.params.id === user.id) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: user
      })
    } else if (req.params.id != user.id) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status: 'fail',
        message: 'No user found with that ID'
      })
    }
    next()
  }
```

})[image: REDIRECTED PAGE]

[image: AFTER A NEW PAGE IS FETCHED]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: instead of using fname, I had to add the reference (user) from the model before calling fname.

```
if user
        a.cta(href='/logout')
          //- img(src="./img/b.jpg", alt="")
          button.header__btn--signup #{user.fname}
```